# JSON WP API Video Embed Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, wp-api

I have an ionic app getting json data and I added Advanced Custom Fields so I can 'embed' a video (youtube, vimeo, etc.) in a post.  The problem is it's only getting the html code ().  How can I have it to where it's actually displaying the video?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get a meta field of your post (ex. id = 123) with wp-api you can do this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: '/wp-json/posts/123/meta',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend:  function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', WP_API_Settings.nonce);
  }
}).done( function( data ) {
  console.log( data );
});
```

If *WP_API_Settings* is not defined you need to load wp-api.js in the enqueue action:

```
wp_register_script( 'myscript', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'myscript.js', array( 'wp-api' ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript' );
```

Comment: I haven't tried v2 yet, it is in beta. I'm using the current stable (1.2.4)